# how to clear data and chach in app using code

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-date

Hello I have an app that I'm developing and I want to clear all of its data when its getting close. I don't mind if it will need to add permission or something like this. also I need it will clear all of my shared preferences.

Comment: What kind of other data are you talking about beside shared preferences?

Comment: Both are same. First will clear data when apps closed. and other when you want for some your activity like as button click and data will clear. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code for delete all data from sharedpreferences.

this is for clear data when apps close:-

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy(); 
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("your prefre name", 0);
 preferences.edit().clear().commit();
}
```

this is when you want to clear all data by any your activity like as button clicked:-

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("your prefre name", 0);
    preferences.edit().clear().commit();
```

it should solve your query.

Comment: I tried the code you sent to me and it didn't work could you explain more about what each part do and if it will clear all of my data i have saved on it or only part of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the shared preferences like this.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("yourpref", 0);
preferences.edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: Yes, just make sure you change "yourpref" to the name that you gave your shared preferences.

Comment: No you don't need to add permissions for this. The first parameter should be the string of the shared preferences. How did you call your shared preferences? What is the name?

Comment: Post what you did...show exactly how you are adding the shared preferences.